# Search functionality in layout page MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello I have build a small blog where I store all my content of the articles in my db. Now I want to add search functionality that I would like to be displayed in every page.

I have read this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-search

But how can I implement search so to have it in my _Layout page? Do I have to use **in any way** partial view for my search? and if yes how can I do that

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by this. Just putting a search box on in your layout that posts to your search action is a trivial affair. You could use a partial, if you wanted, but it's not necessary: you can just plop the form right in the layout. If your search is complex enough that it needs a model, you can utilize a child action to create the model and render a partial view result into the layout.

However, if you're talking about having the actual search results appear *within* the layout, there's not really any reasonable way to accomplish that with MVC. I would recommend, in that case, submitting the search via AJAX and using JavaScript to render the results to the page.

Comment: thank you for your reply! can you post some code or a tutorial how to achive this with ajax?